# When is it OK to use "304.6.2 One-permanent-opening method" for combustion air supply?

Tags: hvac, code-compliance, ducts, natural-gas

My basement utility closet currently uses the "Two-permanent-openings method" with one 5" duct from the attic terminating 12" from the floor and another 6" duct terminating near the ceiling. My understanding of **IRC G2407.6.1 (304.6.1) Two-permanent-openings method** is that the lower duct is supplying fresh air from the outside and the upper duct is "venting" out to create a convective air current in the room. ([source](https://codes.iccsafe.org/s/IRC2015/chapter-24-fuel-gas/IRC2015-Pt06-Ch24-SecG2407.6.1))

Why is the 2nd, higher duct required for venting? Aren't the flue vents doing that already?

Reading up on **G2407.6.2 (304.6.2) One-permanent-opening method** it seems that this would be a simpler method of providing combustion air. Per the same [source](https://codes.iccsafe.org/s/IRC2015/chapter-24-fuel-gas/IRC2015-Pt06-Ch24-SecG2407.6.2):

> Research has shown that for modern appliances, a single opening to the
> outdoors will perform as well as the traditional two-opening method.
> The one-opening method described in this section depends on a reduced
> pressure being created in the enclosure by the draft created by the
> venting system. This reduced pressure causes combustion air to enter
> the enclosure through the single opening.

I understand how both codes work and the sizing requirements, but it's unclear what considerations must be taken into account when choosing one method over the other. Is the one-opening method simply a more updated approach and the two-opening method no longer necessary?

Picture of my utility closet for reference:
[image]